# jquery doesnt recognize div click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have the following code. My issue is that when I click on the div maya, jquery doesn't recognize it and
it will not give me the alert for it.

**CSS**

```
   <style>
   #carousel-single-image {
   width: 320px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: white;
   }
   #carousel-single-image .touchcarousel-container {
   height: 100%;
   background: url("../touchcarousel/demo-images/wood-pattern.jpg") repeat;
   }
   #carousel-single-image .touchcarousel-item {
   margin-right: 0;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   }
   #carousel-single-image img {
   width: 300px;
   height: 360px;
   margin: 32px 0 0 8px;
   float:left;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   padding: 3px;
   background: transparent;
   border: 0;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   }
   #carousel-single-image .tc-paging-container {
   margin-top: -380px;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="productGallery" style="display:none">
   <div id="main-body">
      <div id="carousel-single-image" class="touchcarousel minimal-light">
         <ul class="touchcarousel-container">
            <li class="touchcarousel-item">
               <a href="#"> <img data-original="/image1.jpg" />
               <span class="maya">CheckClick</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="touchcarousel-item">
               <a href="#"> <img data-original="/image2.jpg" />
               <span class="maya">CheckClick</span></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('.maya').click(function(){
alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: Are you including jQuery? Is your jQuery code wrapped in `<script>` tags?

Comment: can you create a fiddle where this does not work? maybe you have another div which have the same content as maya but not the same class so you think you are clicking on maya? does it give any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose in DOM Ready Event , and your script in the script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.maya').click(function(){
            alert("hi");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also make sure the jQuery file is included into your project..

Seems to be [working HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/HbGy5/)

Comment: that didnt work. I already have   $('.maya').click(function(){
            alert("hi");
        });
 in a separate js file on document ready..thanks

Comment: Are you including that file ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle which works... I only took out the display none style on your overall container so I can see it http://jsfiddle.net/wcLn4/

this one with your css http://jsfiddle.net/wcLn4/1/ and without display none